# UITextView drawing text twice

Tags: ios, uitextview

I'm trying to create stroked text on my UITextViews text. It's working fine, but the text is drawing twice on the screen. Here is my drawRect method in the subclass of UITextView...

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    // Drawing code

    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cochin" size:[_fontSize floatValue]];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(1, 1), 1);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context,1,1,1, 1);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, .35);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFillStroke);
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    [[self text] drawInRect:rect withFont:font];
}
```

I tried setting clearsContextOnDraw to YES, but that didn't do the trick. Help please...

Comment: Have you found the solution? I am getting the same problem

Answer (score 3):

I've just tried your code and it does work for me. There are a couple of notes though:

1. You should use `self.bounds` as a target rect to draw to, not the `rect` parameter you get, since it means 'this is the invalid area of your view'. This is a performance optimization and you will rarely need to use it.
2. You don't need to call `CGContextSaveGState` (and when you do, you will want to restore it after that). You would normally do that when you call subroutine that actually modifies the current context (and restore it afterwards), but ideally, this should be moved the routine itself.

Try setting the background of your view white and make font bigger, you might get hints of what's going on. Also, you could post a screenshot here.

UPDATE:

I haven't noticed you were using `UITextView`. You should NOT use this class and do custom drawing! If you wanna draw your text yourself, subclass `UIView`. If you wanna use `UITextView`, use the `attributedString` property of `UITextView` (set it in `viewDidLoad` for example, in your `UIViewController` subclass.
Here's more info on attributed strings: [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52280963/DEV/issueImage.png
This is an image of my issue. The faint layer in the background is the drawRect custom drawing. The black layer in front is the standard drawing of the uitextview from its superview.

Answer (score 2):

Oh boy, the text system is a complex beast of many, many (mostly private) classes, methods and data structures.

You have NSTextStorage, NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and UITextView as the public classes. Throw in UITextRange and UITextPosition for good measure. On Mac OS X you also have typesetter classes.

While UITextView asks the NSLayoutManager to draw text in certain rect regions (via a private method instead of drawRect), the drawing itself is actually done by NSLayoutManager. If you want to draw the text yourself, you'll have to provide your own NSLayoutManager subclass.

Use a NSLayoutManager subclass as a last resort. Either use a custom uiview to draw the frame and text yourself, or use uitextview and try to figure out whereby the system is drawing text. You'll need the NSLayoutManager methods for that. Draw the frames, but not the text in drawRect of your uitextview class.

Answer (score 0):

You should never call drawRect directly.

Instead of:

```
[[self text] drawInRect:rect withFont:font];
```

Try:

```
[[self text] setNeedsDisplayInRect:rect];
```

Comment: Note that he's not calling `UIView`'s method `drawRect` directly, but `drawInRect` of `NSString` which is different and totally fine.

Comment: That didn't work. Its still drawing the text views twice. The first time it executes the custom drawing code in drawRect. Than on top of that it draws the text from the textview with its default values. I set the color to clear color and that solved it, but it seems like a hackjob. My question is how to I make drawRect stop the default rendering of the uitextview?

Answer (score 0):

I use this to avoid this problem

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

    //YOUR Drawing code here ...

    self.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```